# Check if the list is a structured subset of the main set

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have defined 3 sets :

```
List<List<string>> validOrders = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "01", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "04", "01", "05", "06" },
};
```

and I have a subset called as "childObjectsPrefix" which I have defined as:

```
List<string> childObjectsPrefix = new List<string> { "01", "04" }; //This can be dynamic, can be a subset of 1 or even 4 or 5
```

So I run my code to check if "childObjectsPrefix" is a subset of any of sets from "validOrders", it should output "childObjectsPrefix is not a subset of validOrders.", right? Because I want to check if the elements in childObjectsPrefix appear consecutively in any of the validOrders lists.

but it does not. It outputs "childObjectsPrefix is a subset of validOrders." for some strange reason. How do I fix it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

// Define a function to check if a list is a subset of another list while preserving the order.
bool IsSubsetInOrder(List<string> listToCheck, List<string> referenceList)
{
    int listIndex = 0;
    foreach (var item in referenceList)
    {
        if (listIndex < listToCheck.Count && listToCheck[listIndex] == item)
        {
            listIndex++;
            if (listIndex == listToCheck.Count)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Your valid orders list
List<List<string>> validOrders = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "01", "04", "05", "06" },
    new List<string> { "02", "03", "04", "01", "05", "06" },
};

// Your childObjectsPrefix
List<string> childObjectsPrefix = new List<string> { "01", "04" };

bool isSubset = validOrders.Any(order => IsSubsetInOrder(childObjectsPrefix, order));

if (isSubset)
{
    // childObjectsPrefix is a subset of at least one list in validOrders
    Console.WriteLine("childObjectsPrefix is a subset of validOrders.");
}
else
{
    // childObjectsPrefix is not a subset of any list in validOrders
    Console.WriteLine("childObjectsPrefix is not a subset of validOrders.");
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what it means for you that a subset is in order? The first order list clearly contains 01 and 04 in the right order. Do they need to be together, so one after the other, `"01", "04", ...` instead of `"01", "02", "03", "04"`?

Comment: I think he meant ["01","04"] do not belong in any "structured" set. It's a subset ofc but none have indexes 0 as 01 and 1 as 04 in either of the 3 sets.

Comment: This is exactly what i want. Sorry for using the term "subset".

Comment: @Yidi: now that you clarified the requirement you should consider to change your question including the title. Otherwise people who have a similar requirement don't get help.